# Safari opens a bookmark when I insert media

Tags: macos, finder, safari, ssd

I am getting strange behavior, and I'm not sure where to start.

Each time I insert an SD card into my card reader, Safari comes to the foreground and pops open the same old bookmarked page (not the default). Is this a system thing or a Safari thing?

Anyone know where I should look?

Safari version 13.1
OSX 10.14.6